# what does the decreasing numbers in stack trace in Mac process hang report means?

Tags: macos, crash-reports, freeze, crash-dumps

I have a Mac application that hangs when a command is executed. When I force quit this application, Mac generates a report with the current stack trace. The stack trace looks like:

> 14 start + 53 (App 14.0) [0x2955]
>       14 main + 164 (App 14.0) [0x444f5f]
>           13 Paste + 53 (App 14.0) [0x2955]
>               12 PasteInternal + 164 (App 14.0) [0x444f5f]  and so on...

Wondering what does the prefixed numbers (14, 13, 12...) mean here? Is it the number of times this method is called?

Comment: Are you sure the first one is also 14, not 15?

Comment: @ThomasW.:Yes, I have posted a sample but yes the real trace has a number of 14s then couple of 13s then 12s and so on.